# Visual Studio 2015: increase process memory

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2015, resources

When I'm running my application in Visual Studio 2015, I see in the diagnostic tools that the process memory is stuck to 2GB - as if there was a limit:

[image: Diagnostic]

I read, that executing for `x32` limits the available memory, so that it is necessary to use `x64`. So I build `relase, x64` which gives me the result shown above. How can I remove this "limit"?

Note: I have 16GB Ram hardware (OS: Windows 10).

Comment: If you build for x64, then there is no memory limit. Check your application if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: There's a somewhat obscure `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag that tells the OS you can deal with pointers that have their top bit set to `1`. This gives you ~4GB of memory, assuming you run your 32 bits process on a 64 bits OS. It's very safe in C++, because C++ makes no assumptions about that bit. But native x64 code gives you way more than 4GB of memory.

Comment: Actually, @MSalters comment is important. If it's set to `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:No` in the Visual Studio config page, then the maximum memory usage limit will be **2GB**, just as your image shows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such limit, this is probably your code (or some library, that you use) uses exactly 2gb of ram.

If you try to allocate more than 2GB of memory in x86 application - you'll get std::bad_alloc exception, since OS is unable to provide more, despite, that you have 14GB more free memory.

Very simple program in MSVC2015 compiled as x64, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; ++i) {
    char* ch = new char[1024];
}
```

eats 4gb of RAM, and no limit is imposed by default configuration.

Comment: Thank you! This code behaved as you said - exception with `x86`  and 4GB with `x64`. In my code, I use OpenCV, Cuda and Intel TBB. Do you know any limits there?

Comment: @black no idea, you need to check separately for each library.

Answer (score 1):

The Diagnostic tool settings define Limit values for the use of resources. You should unckeck this option.